# CURL in CodeIgniter Unauthorized with Google Cloud Messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I have a simple problem in here.
Im using GCM to send notifications from my server to android devices.
To send them Im using CURL to the Google CLoud.
However when I try to send Im getting Unauthorized error.
If I run the code as a simple php script without the CI it`s OK.
It seems to me that the problem is in CI configuration.

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids = 0, $message) {

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => array($registatoin_ids),
        'data' => array($message),
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $this->api_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    $result;
}
```

Comment: `It seems to me that the problem is in CI configuration` I don't see any code related to CI here. How could we help then?

Comment: Is there correct api_key property in your class?

Comment: The API key is ok.The problem is in CI!Because when the code is out.. there`s no problem.The question is why,and what is stopping it.